# Unable to restar SSH after editing SSH config

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ubuntu-16.04

I installed openssh-server in ubuntu and configured in using this link

```
https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-enable-ssh-ubuntu/
```

I uncommented the #22 in the config file to allow connections to port 22

I have a TP-Link router and have done port forwarding but am still not able to connect to my machine using SSH. I put the IP of the router in port forwarding section. 
What am I doing wrong ? Complete newbie to SSH.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe what steps you performed to install and configure ssh. Don't expect people to follow the link and read the howto. Include your sshd_config file and point out any changes you made while installing it. Tell us exactly what happens when you try to connect to the server through ssh. Do you get any error messages? What do they say?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Tanmay Bhatnagar !!

For linux, `22` is default port for `OpenSSH`. It doesn't matter if you uncommented it because `OpenSSH server` run on `port 22.`

As you are setting up server `SSH port` by port forwarding with public IP. Kindly check whether you are able to connect privately. If not, check service status and port using below commands.

check service status -

```
# systemctl status sshd

# service sshd status
```

For port connection -

```
# netstat -tulpn

# ss --tulpn
```

NOTE : If you are able to connect in private network. Kindly check your router setting.